# Resizing NSTableView makes text not clear

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have this problem that when I setframe of the parent view of the NSTableView the text goes unclear and blurry (doubled text over others), but when I switch tabs between application or click in a row the text go right again,

I was trying to call tableview setNeedDisplay with no results?

do you have any idea how I can solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by enabling Core Animation Layer form Interface builder